# Flexbox positioning and background

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've just started using flexbox and I've tried to center a span element with a background both horizontally and vertically, the only problem is that when I give the span a display: flex; and height: 100%, the background spreads across the entire site and it looks like this.

[image]

Is it possible to get rid of the green background covering the entire site and make it cover the text only while using flexbox? Thanks in advance

```css
.box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Title</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
     <meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<span class="box">
    TEST
</span>
```

Comment: if you want to cover just the text I would recommend you used inline-block( if you want to add padding, change width) or just inline instead of flex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you set the basic **flex** rules for the    `span` tag. It is not right! I advise you to wrap `span` in an additional container, and set this container to transfer all **flex** rules from `span`. But to leave the `span` only `background: green`.

If you have any questions, please let me know. I will answer you with pleasure.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;   
}

.box {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Title</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
     <meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<div class="main">
  <span class="box">
      TEST
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your body has the `height: 100%;` that's why your flexbox container `.box` also get this height as you are again setting `.box` height to 100%. So your `.box` flex container when set the `height` of 100% takes it's parents `height` which is the `body`.

```
.box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%; /* This height is w.r.t parent which is body */
    background: green;
}
```

```css
.box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 50%; /* You need to set this as per your requirement */
    background: green;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Title</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
     <meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<span class="box">
    TEST
</span>
```